Which BASIC dialect first featured a single-character comment introducer?
Beside REM Extended BASIC uses the apostrophe for comments, what was the earliest reference?
TI Extended BASIC uses the exclamation mark, is there any standard?

I would say REM is the only standardised keyword for comments and even then it's not a standard in the sense that the C language has standards.

@AlanB - Well, there is ANSI X3.60-1978, Minimal BASIC, which basically (!) standardizes Dartmouth BASIC.

Oric basic uses tick (')

What implementation do you mean by your first mention of 'extended BASIC' in the question ?

Out of sheer curiosity, why do you ask?

@Keltari Because of https://github.com/cc65/cc65/pull/2436

The apostrophe as a comment marker appeared in Dartmouth BASIC v4 of 1968.
See page 52 (original page numbering) of reference.
Tymshare SUPER BASIC of the same year introduced !. I was unaware anyone else had used it.

If the main thrust of the question is "what was the earliest..." then this is surely the answer.

DEC BASIC-PLUS for the PDP-11 and DG's Extended BASIC for the Nova both allowed ! remark statements. Much later, Frank Ostrowski's GFA BASIC for the Atari ST also allowed this style of comment. The editor may have replaced blank lines with exclamation marks, as blank lines weren't allowed in GFA BASIC.

Sure, but RSTS-11 was a 1970s OS, so not the earliest example.

+1 I just checked my hardcopy of the previous (1 January 1966) version of this manual, and, sure enough, "REM" is documented, but not the apostrophe. FWIW, the very first ever BASIC program ran on May 1, 1964. Search YouTube for "The Birth of BASIC" to learn the history from many of the people who were there.

@dave - I was mostly responding to Maury's "I was unaware anyone else had used it."

A fair number of early implementations didn't have a REDIM, and recognized REM based on just the R, so although not documented as such, it was effectively a sinlge-character comment introducer--I remember one that started with something like 100 REINTRODUCING <MY GAME>..., which was accepted as a comment on a fair number of BASIC implementations of the time.

Is there a standard?  Yes, there are two.
ANSI X3.60-1978, also ECMA-55, Minimal BASIC, allows only REM.  REM of course is a statement in its own right.
ANSI X3.113-1987 also ECMA-116, Full BASIC, not commonly implemented, allows REM and '!'.  The latter is a 'tail comment', allowed on the same physical line as other statements.
Any other remark indicators are implementation-specific extensions to the standardized language(s).

The ANSI/ECMA standards may have been attempts at a de jure standard, but the Minimal BASIC standard was a little too minimal and a little too late to set standard usage. ANSI Full BASIC was entirely irrelevant by the time the standard came out. Demonstrating Minimal BASIC compatibility was helpful to show (US) Federal Information Processing Standard (FIPS) compliance, however, and Microsoft BASIC-80 claimed it was compliant in its manual

Nevertheless, a standard is a standard, even if it is ratified in the forest when no-one is around to hear it fall.

Relevant links: https://ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-55/  and https://ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-116/

"Any other remark indicators are implementation-specific extensions to the standardized language(s)." At least to me it seems pretty silly to call something an extension to a standard, when (in the vast majority of cases) the standard didn't exist yet when the "extension" was written.

Fair enough.  But then most of them were extensions to BASIC as defined by its inventors.
